# eclipse(set with scala envirnment) : object apache is not a member of package org

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

[image]

As shown in image, its giving error when i am importing the Spark packages. Please  help. When i hover there, it shows "object apache is not a member of package org". 
I searched on this error, it shows spark jars has not been imported. So, i imported "spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.2.0.jar" too. But still same error.Below is what i actually want to run:

```
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
 object ABC {

 def main(args: Array[String]){
//Scala Main Method

println("Spark Configuration")

val conf = new SparkConf()

conf.setAppName("My First Spark Scala Application")

conf.setMaster("spark://ip-10-237-224-94:7077")

println("Creating Spark Context")
}
}
```

Comment: Have you added spark-core jar in your classpath?

Comment: Actually i dont exactly which all jars to add and at which location are they on spark, from where i can copy. Could you just guide?

Comment: You simply need to follow instructions in https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html

Comment: after adding the spak-core, do Maven -> update Project, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `spark-core` jar in your classpath should resolve your issue. Also if you are using some build tools like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) (if not then you should because spark-core has lot many dependencies and you would keep getting such problem for different jars), try to use Eclipse task provided by these tools to properly set classpath in your project.

Comment: is this the jar you are referring to -> "/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/1.4.1/spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.jar"? Please help

Comment: Yes, that's the jar.

Answer (score 2):

I was also receiving the same error, in my case it was compatibility issue. As Spark 2.2.1 is not compatible with Scala 2.12(it is compatible with 2.11.8) and my IDE was supporting Scala 2.12.3. 
I resolved my error by

1) Importing the jar files from the basic folder of Spark. During the installation of Spark in our C drive we have a folder named Spark which contains Jars folder in it. In this folder one can get all the basic jar files. 
Goto to Eclipse right click on the project -> properties-> Java Build Path. Under 'library' category we will get an option of ADD EXTERNAL JARs.. Select this option and import all the jar files of 'jars folder'. click on Apply.

2) Again goto properties -> Scala Compiler ->Scala Installation -> Latest 2.11 bundle (dynamic)*
*before selecting this option one should check the compatibility of SPARK and SCALA.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Scala is **NOT backward compatible**. Hence each Spark module is complied against specific Scala library. But when we run from eclipse,  we have one SCALA VERSION which was used to compile and create the spark Dependency Jar which we add to the build path, and SECOND SCALA VERSION is there as the eclipse run time environment. **Both may conflict**.

This is a hard reality,  although, we wish Scala to be ,backward compatible. Or at least a complied jar file created could be backward compatible.
*Hence, the recommendation is , use Maven or similar where dependency version can be managed.*

Answer (score -2):

If you are doing this in the context of Scala within a Jupyter Notebook, you'll get this error.  You have to install the **Apache Toree** kernel:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree

and create your notebooks with that kernel.

You also have to start the Jupyter Notebook with:

```
pyspark
```

Comment: seems like this asnwer is for some other issue