# Why when Maven Build Works good but adding Spark Jar as external Jars gives a compile error “object Apache is not a member of package org”

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark, hadoop

On Eclipse, while setting up spark , even after adding external jars to build path to `spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/<_all.jar>`, 
Complier complains about '`“object apache is not a member of package org''`

Yes, Building dependencies via Maven or SBT would fix it. A question is asked 
[scalac compile yields "object apache is not a member of package org"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269836/scalac-compile-yields-object-apache-is-not-a-member-of-package-org)

**But** Question over here is , **WHY** the traditional way is failing like this ?

Comment: Can you show how you set up your build path in Eclipse, the particular import statement and the jar file that should have contained the package you are trying to import?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714920/eclipseset-with-scala-envirnment-object-apache-is-not-a-member-of-package-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we reffer here , [Scala/Spark version compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883325/scala-spark-version-compatibility) We could see a similar issue. The problem is **Scala is NOT backward compatible**. Hence each Spark module is complied against specific Scala library. But when we run from eclipse, the eclipse Scala environment may not be compatible that particular scala version of which we have the Spark libraries set up.

Comment: How do you check which Scala environment is set up in Eclipse and how can you make it match the Spark module that you want to use?

Comment: Set Scala Installation option in Eclipse would help you to toggle among some set of Scala Installations. Where as Spark that you may avail , and other libraries that you may avail, you need to double check if you have the matching Scala in eclipse.
BUT WHY.. Scala decided not to be backward compatible, although it came if Solve problems of Java and created more complexity to suit to an environment.

Comment: Scala development environments should understand this and make sure to automatically pull in the right version. For example in SBT, you say `%%` instead of `%` when specifying the dependency version. That selects the proper one based on your Scala version.